# Function to return current half quarter and previous two quarters based on current date

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a variable (`suffix`) that prints current year and quarter in this format: `'_21_q2'` and (`previous_suffix`) which is simply suffix - 2 quarters in this case: `'_21_q2'`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
currrent_date = datetime.datetime.now()
current_year = str(x.year)[2:]
current_quarter = str(((x.month-1)//3)+1)
suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + currentquarter)
previous_suffix = ?
```

Desired output

```
suffix = '_22_q1'
previous_suffix = '_21_q2'
```

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: Wouldn't the quarter previous to 22Q1 be 21Q4, not 21Q2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `strftime` instead of calling `str` on a `datetime` object.

That said, here is one way leveraging `pd.Period` (since you have a `pandas` tag anyway):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def format_quarter(date):
    year = date.strftime('%y')
    quarter = pd.Period(date, freq='q').strftime('%q')

    return f'_{year}_q{quarter}_'

# You're better off choosing a date first and formatting it afterwards
d1 = datetime.now()
d2 = d1 - pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(3)

suffix = format_quarter(d1)
previous_suffix = format_quarter(d2)
```

Output:

```
In [18]: suffix                                                                                        
Out[18]: '_22_q1_'

In [19]: previous_suffix                                                                               
Out[19]: '_21_q2_'
```